# Delphi FireMonkey botão em tTabControl não responde

Tags: delphi, button, firemonkey

Estou criando uma App com o `Berlin Starter Edition`. Coloquei um `tTabControl` no `Form`, criei uma `Tab` e coloquei um `tButton` nela. Tanto o `tTabControl` quanto o `tButton` estão `Enabled`. Porém quando rodo o programa, o botão não reage (com se não estivesse `Enabled`). Alguem tem alguma dica? Grato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

O botão não reage porque no `Style` do `tTabControl` foi inserido um `tRectangle` para dar cor de fundo. Embora o texto do botão aparece, estou clicando no `tRectangle`. Não adianta enviar o `tRectangle` para trás e nem o botão para frente. Tem que achar outro modo de dar cor de fundo ao `tTabControl` que não seja inserindo um `tRectangle` no `Style`.

Alguém tem uma dica?

Answer (score 0):

A solução é só marcar a propriedade `Enabled` do `tRectangle` como `False`.